# Is it possible to switch shells without getting dumped into the old shell by exit?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, sh, fish

For example, let's say I have `bash, sh, fish, zsh, pwsh` or more installed.

If I start `bash`, switching into `sh` leads to the following:

```
user@device:/folder/directory$ sh
$ exit
user@device:/folder/directory$ exit

-- Session actually ends.
```

What I would like is to be able to do this:

```
user@device:/folder/directory$ switchto fish
user@device /f/directory> switchto zsh
device% exit

-- Session actually ends.
```

Is there something of the sort that does **not** close the terminal? For example, a super-shell (maybe `shmgr`) which is used as the default shell and provides such a command (maybe `switchsh`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `exec` command to replace one interactive shell with another. From `man bash` for example (where `exec` is provided as a shell builtin command)

> ```
>    exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
>           If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new  process
>           is  created.
> ```

What happens after that depends: if the original shell was a login shell, then the session will terminate. If the shell is an interactive shell running in a terminal emulator for example, then the terminal emulator application decides what to do: for `gnome-terminal` you have a choice under the `Edit` -> `Preferences` menu between closing the terminal, not closing the terminal (leaving it rather useless - without a shell) or relaunching the default shell.

Comment: This is definitely correct (though `exec` is more powerful than readers might assume from this: the `exec`ing shell needn't be interactive and the external command it `exec`s it needn't even be a shell). It works from Bourne-style shells as well as `tcsh` and `fish`. But I'm curious if `pwsh` (PowerShell), mentioned in the question, has an `exec` command or equivalent. It runs on \*nix systems but is not really a Unix-style shell. (In Windows, it doesn't seem to, though I may be missing something. On Ubuntu I've installed the snap but I not managed to make it run, so I haven't tested in that.)

Comment: @EliahKagan yes I didn't mean to imply that it can't be used to replace other processes, just that it *can* be used to replace interactive shells ;)